# Crear un Login con Autenticación de tipos de Usuario usando Visual Studio(c#) y SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

En la Escuela me dejaron un proyecto dónde debo crear un **Login** y **Autentificar** los tipos de usuarios por ejemplo:

Si el usuario es **Administrador** que lo lleve al formulario principal donde podrá buscar, agregar, eliminar y modificar. Ahora bien si es **Usuario** que lo lleve al mismo formulario principal pero sólo podrá buscar.

> Pensaba que a la hora de iniciar sesión los lleve al mismo formulario
>   pero dependiendo de qué tipo de usuario sea se activen o se desactiven
>   algunos botones

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Muestra lo que haz intentado, el sitio es para prestar ayuda con problemas concretos de programación. Te recomiendo hacer el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ganar tu primera medalla además de revisar la sección [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que ya sabes usar clases, conectarte a bases de datos y crear, leer, borrar y modificar registros.

Si no tienes que usar las autenticaciones de .Net lo mas simple es solo con la base de datos.

1. En tu base de datos crea una tabla de usuarios con un capo de roles (admin o usuario final)
2. En tu aplicacion crea un clase objeto de usuarios con las mismas propiedades de tu tabla incluyendo los roles.
3. En tu metodo de login solo vas a crear una variable de sesion del tipo de tu clase usuarios que creaste la cual vas a llenar con la consulta del usuario que se esta iniciando sesion.
4. Hecha la consulta en ese metodo redireccionas al formulario
5. En el load de tu formulario lee lo que trae la variable de sesion (las variables de sesion son como variables globales que podras usar en cualquier formulario a menos de que la limpies, la cambies o el tiempo de sesion se acabe). 
   Instancias tu clase usuarios `Users usuario = new Users();` e igualala a la sesion `usuario=Session["user"];` Si la variable de sesion viene nula redirecciona al login, sino valida el rol `if (usuario.rol = "Admin"){...}else{...}`. Si el usuario es diferente de admin, solo deja visibles los controles que usas para hacer la busqueda.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta, acabo de empezar a programar en VS c# y hay muchas cosas que aún no manejo